# Assign IF statement result with two result variables (IF, THEN, AND?)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hmmm I can't find the best way to do this.  Plus, this code doesn't work anyway.  I want the text of "January" (and all 12 months) returned with two variables:

```
If month = "January" Then
        days = "31" And monthnum = "1"
End If
```

Suggestions?

Syntax that finally worked:

```
If month = "January" Then
        days = 31
        mon = 1
    ElseIf month = "February" Then
        days = 29
         mon = 2
'elseif for the rest of the months
End If
```

Comment: How are you going to handle the leap/regular year for February? I hope this code is just for exercise, otherwise this issue can lead to... unpredictable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this VBA syntext

```
Dim days As Integer
Dim monthnum As Integer

'if then elseif end

If Month = "January" Then
        days = 31
        monthnum = 1
ElseIf Month = "February" Then
        days = 28
        monthnum = 2
ElseIf Month = "March" Then
        days = 31
        monthnum = 1
 ' repeat for all other months
End If
```

Comment: lol.. of course.  The one thing I didn't think to try. :)  Thank you!

Comment: This works, but without the "set".  Since it's equal to a number it's not an object, so i get the error "compile error, object missing".  However, removing the "set" works.

Comment: Set is removed from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming english locale you could

```
sMonth = "april"

monthnum = month("1 " & sMonth)
days = day(dateserial(2001,iif(monthnum=12, 1, monthnum+1),0))
```

Comment: you can just use `monthmun+1`: excel doesn't worry about day 0 of month 13, as it translates that to the last day of month 12, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Case statement

```
Sub MonthValue()

For b 1 To 20

Select Case Range("A" & a).Value
Case January, March, May, June, August, October, December
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = 31
Case Feburary
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = 28
Case April, June, September, November
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = 30
Case Else ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = 0
End Select

Next b
End Sub
```